# How to use redirect to open link in new tab in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect

I have a form on which submit I want to redirect to another page but I want to open the redirected page in a new tab.

```
if (requestedDownloadLink != null)
{
    return Redirect(requestedDownloadLink);
}
```

Comment: The project you are using is asp.net core mvc 2.0 or asp.net core razor page 2.0？
Can you provide more details about your current code?
If allowed, complete it in `js`  is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Return a model from action with redirect url. Define model class

```
public class ResultModel
{
    public string RedirectUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Create and return model

```
var result = new ResultModel
{
    RedirectUrl = requestedDownloadLink
};
return Ok(result);
```

Then open new tab in javascript as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/7775908).

```
function openInNewTab(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}

openInNewTab(response.redirectUrl);
```